# B2C as SAML IDP can no longer be set up after breaking change to identifierUris

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I am currently implementing SAML sign in for our B2C tenants based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy). I already did this a couple of weeks ago as a proof of concept. However, the recent [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#appid-uri-in-single-tenant-applications-will-require-use-of-default-scheme-or-verified-domains) now prevents me from implementing the solution.

I now get this error when I try to set up the `identifierUris`.

```
Failed to update B2C-SamlSignIn application. Error detail: Values of IdentifierUris property must use a verified domain of the organization or its subdomain:
```

In my working proof of concept, I had a identifierUrl which does not fit into the new requirements for the domain. Without it, the solution is no longer working with the external application I am trying to connect. I get a redirect loop when I initiate login. The loop indicates that the removed identifierUri is the issue:

```
<samlp:StatusMessage>Application registered corresponding to IssuerUri https://someotherdomain/somethingspecific in AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL https://someotherdomain/somethingspecific/broker/saml/endpoint specified in its metadata.</samlp:StatusMessage><samlp:StatusDetail>
```

`https://someotherdomain/somethingspecific` is the value I had set up before. I cannot change the entityId in the other application.

Is there a way to get it working again? I tried creating a new application which has "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)", but the same restrictions seem to apply there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change made. in the App manifest, update the **accessTokenAcceptedVersion** to: `2`.

> If you do not update the accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 you will recieve an error message requiring a verified domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-the-identifier

Comment: I still had the tab open from last Friday, without the new updates. Seems the documentation was updated just in time, awesome!

Comment: So I am having the same issue and I have accessTokenAcceptedVersion set to 2 and it still errors. have they rebroken it?

Answer (score 0):

@doodlleus - For me it still works, but only if i choose the correct "Support type".
When creating the app, select e.g.

> Accounts in this organizational directory only (... - Single tenant)

Once created, the manifest will have the "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" attribute set to "null", which i changed to "2" and then i could set "identifierUris"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).